# `__heap_base` seems to be missing in clang 9.0.0, is there a replacement?

Tags: c, llvm, llvm-clang, webassembly

I'm trying to compile a C library of mine for WebAssembly, using clang (no emscripten), and it compiles fine with `clang` version `8.0.1`, but fails with `clang` version `9.0.0`. The reported error is `wasm-ld: error: ….o: undefined symbol: __heap_base`. Has `__heap_base` been replaced with some other symbol?

The library is open source and compilation instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/GeorgeLyon/Opaque#webassembly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I believe I found the culprit: the linker in `9.0.0` seems to require the `--export=__heap_base` (`-Wl,--export=__heap_base` for the `clang`). This works for my project.

Comment: But you shouldn't need to export the symbol to use it internally.   This is a bug in llvm 9.0 which was fixed in https://reviews.llvm.org/D65920.   So I think we need to backport this fix.

Answer (score 2):

This does seem to be bug in 9.0.0.  It doesn't seem to occur with ToT or with 8.0.0.

Simple repro case:

```
extern void* __heap_base;

void* a = &__heap_base;

void _start() {
}
```

Build with:

`$ clang --target=wasm32 test.c -nostdlib -Wl,-no-gc-sections`

With 9.0.0:

```
wasm-ld: error: /tmp/test-551a5c.o: undefined symbol: __heap_base
clang-9: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This should be opened as bug in the llvm bug tracker.